# Android read browser history

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

I want to read browser history in Android phone.

I have done some document reading, then I come to know that we can read browser history by android.provider.Browser class.  It has :

```
final static Cursor
getAllVisitedUrls(ContentResolver cr)
```

...method which returns `Cursor`.

May I get help to handle Cursor, or any example code to get browser history?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not really an answer but I can tell you what I did.

I first clone the [browser repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=summary) and try to reproduce how they get the history.
And I started getting:

> Permission Denial: reading
> com.android.browser.BrowserProvider

So I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

But it still is giving me the same error. I google it and I found this [Accessing Data With Android Cursors](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/3/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: The permission should be: `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />` It works then.

Comment: @Firebrandt: I just fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Does this method require root access, or just that single permission?

Comment: @ethanpil.. no root access required buddy

Comment: This answer is not completed, after I try so many times, I discovered the other part of problem was the AVD. so install AVD with API 18 (I was running API 23) then I was able to run it. I don't sure why this process is so picky.

Comment: This will not work in Marshmallow anymore: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Answer (score 18):

managedQuery has been deprecated so use getContentResolver instead, use the following code:

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, null);
mCur.moveToFirst();
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String title = "";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
String url = "";
if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
    boolean cont = true;
    while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
        title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
        url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        // Do something with title and url
        mCur.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Also add permissions using

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

Comment: this answer works! I also made an example based on this answer
https://github.com/shanwu/shanwu_coding_base/tree/bookmark_record_example

Comment: [Most things related to Bookmarks were removed in API Level 23 (Android 6.0+)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)

Answer (score 9):

**For Lollipop or earlier**

I am able to get the history by using the following code:

```
Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
            if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
                while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                    Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                    mCur.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Log.v("urlIdx", mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX)); try this out. and for further info please visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html

Comment: This will not work in Marshmallow anymore: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser

Answer (score 5):

This post is a little bit old, but here is another easy solution for getting data related to `Bookmark` and `Search` content providers in Android:

Use this lib: https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers

Get all bookmarks:

```
BrowserProvider browserProvider = new BrowserProvider(context);
List<Bookmark> bookmarks = browserProvider.getBookmarks().getList();
```

Each **Bookmark** has all fields, so you can get any info you need:
*title, url, visits, ...*

Get all **Search** history:

```
List<Search> searches = browserProvider.getSearches().getList();
```

It works with lists or cursor and there a sample app to see how it looks and works.

In fact, there is support for all Android content providers like: *Contacts, SMS, Calls, ...*
Full doc with all options: https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers/wiki/Android-providers

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  public ArrayList<HistoryEntry> getBrowserHistory() {

    String title = "";
    String url = "";

    ArrayList<HistoryEntry> list = new ArrayList<HistoryEntry>();

    String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
            Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history,
                                                            // 1 = bookmark
    Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj,
            sel, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();

    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        boolean cont = true;
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
            HistoryEntry entry = new HistoryEntry();

            title = mCur.getString(mCur
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            url = mCur.getString(mCur
                    .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            // Do something with title and url
            entry.setTitle(title);
                            entry.setUrl(url);
                            list.add(entry );
            Log.d("TAG", "title   " + title);
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    mCur.close();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: [Most things related to Bookmarks were removed in API Level 23 (Android 6.0+)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)