# create custom browser for android

Tags: android

I'm developing a browser for android. I simply need to create one search editbox with a history button.

When the user clicks 'history' button,  up to five recent visited webpages should be presented.

I don't know where to start... Because I have no idea on how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom browser for that. You can embed a WebView in your app.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

In this, you can get last 5 pages from History using JavaScript and display those URLs.

Comment: .Thanks for ur quick reply..But is there any api available to get the history details.?

Answer (score 0):

You should check WebView in android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

If you want to customize it , extend webview class and you can go ahead from there.

Comment: thanks for ur reply..But i just wanna know how to retrieve last 5 visited web pages?& even when i click any one i've to go to that page..

Comment: For that you will have to use Content providers of Browser , some examples suggests that you have to use bookmark content provider and extract bookmarks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history . This might help you. Once you get bookmarked url , its easy to launch that website using loadUrl API of webview.