# How to delete bookmark

Tags: android, webview, history, bookmarks

How to delete bookmark you get from

```
android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI
```

I got bookmark listed, how to get history of website visited?

EDIT

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_DELETE, 0, "DELETE");
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_ITEM_DELETE:
        int urlIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);
        String url = mCursor.getString(urlIndex);
        contentResolver.delete(Uri.parse(url), item.getTitle().toString(), null);
    }
    return false;
}
```

What can I do in:

```
contentResolver.delete(Uri.parse(url), item.getTitle().toString(), null);
```

to delete bookmark at that listview position when long click on that bookmark?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get `ContentResolver` instance.

you can get it as follows:

```
ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
```

ctx is `Context` instance.

then there is a `delete` method in `ContentResolver`, signature is as follows:

```
delete(url, where, selectionArgs)
```

put your url in place of url(`Url.parse("android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI")`), a valid where clause and selection arguments. and you are done.

Then you need to add some permissions as per your implementations. But i guess you would need these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.broswer.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

you can get more info about this on the following [link](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/3/)

also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history).

Thanks