# get my own browser history android

Tags: android, browser-history

I'm developing my own web browser, and i want get this browser's history, so i used this code to get it :

```
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, whereClause, null, orderBy);

    mCur.moveToFirst();
    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Log.v("titleIdx", mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
            Log.v("urlIdx", mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

but i realized that this code give out the history of the default android browser, so I want to know if there is a similar way to get my own web browser's history from android databases, or I should save every url myself when the user is browsing the web?

thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history

Comment: no, it's not the same question, what i want is to get my own web browser history, not the default android browser that i can get by using the code that i gave above

Answer (score 0):

so you created your own android browser? are you using webview?
you probably need to keep track of your own history then.