# how can i retrieve navigation history on android programmatically?

Tags: android, navigation

I want to extract the history of my Internet navigation on android. Is there any one that knows how to do it programmatically ?

Comment: i'm sorry internet navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name=
    "com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

...then query for a `Cursor`...

```
Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
            mCur.moveToFirst();
            if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                    Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                    mCur.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

[Sour](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/3/)[ces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583150/493749)

Comment: @emna My pleasure. Please accept the answer once you see it working well.