# Is it possible for a Android application to extract the SQLite databse from another application?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm interested in getting the SQLite database containing browsing history from the built in browser exporting it to an SD card. I want to application to do this rather than using ADB.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot. This would be a huge security risk.