# searching through android browser history

Tags: android, search, browser, keyword, browser-history

Although I have found some code to retrieve android browser history, the program I'm trying to write requires that it becomes searchable for keywords. Can someone help me organize the history into a list? I am in new territory, so source/tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

The code I found (2nd answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/2583150/1406409

Sorry for any typos, but I'm trying tpo get used to typing on a tablet.

Comment: You forgot "The code I found", and I don't know what "(2nd answer)" means. :-)

Comment: From the link you posted, you just need to replace the two calls to `Log.v` with addition to a list or two-dimensional array. What have you tried so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: Could you post that as an answer with working source code?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I'm not a Java programmer, and StackOverflow is not a code writing service or a "teach me to program" site. If you try and do it yourself and have problems, post what you've tried and someone here can try to help you. We don't do your work for you, though. :-)

Comment: I was gonna mark you as an accepted answer, getting you your rep. I already have the working app.

Comment: I appreciate it, but as I said I'm not a Java programmer. :-) You should post your working code as an answer yourself, so that it's helpful to others in the future who find this question in a search. You can even accept it as correct once enough time has passed.