# How to Access Opera mini and Firefox browsing history in Android application

Tags: android, firefox, browser

Is there anyway to access opera mini and Firefox's browsing history? 
I want to access these histories from other application so can u please suggest me the way how can i do this thing?

Is this possible to read firefox sqlite database and get it from there?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2578345/1503130 Are you sure this doesn't help you

Comment: @pKs Its only work for android default browser. i am looking for firefox opera any 3rd party browser's history access or its application filestrucure..

Comment: Didn't you find some content providers from them and I guess they don't.