# Retrieve history from Google Chrome on Android

Tags: android

Let us say that I am writing an Android application that needs to get the browsing history of Google Chrome. Does the Android API allow for this? Which versions? What code could do this?

Comment: did you find any solution? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer in this SO post:

[Android read browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history)

Basically, you need the Cursor interface for this purpose, and manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```