# How to access browser history android

Tags: android, android-browser

I am developing an app that should access the browser history.
I know that from Android 6 the apps has to provide their own access to their content provider but I didn't find any specific documentation on this.
Does anyone succeeded in extracting the history/bookmark from browsers as Chrome, Firefox... ?

Please, keep in mind that starting from Android 6 the READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS and WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permissions are removed
([link to docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser)).

Really thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android read browser history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history)

Comment: In the Android M docs google has stated that
"Bookmarks and subscribed feeds permissions are removed."