# It is possible to keep track of the visited URLs on an Android or iOS device?

Tags: android, ios, web, browser

I have an idea to create an application on Android and iOS that tracks the number of times a user visits a website. I want to know when a user enters a website, for example google, twitter, or facebook and indicate that the user entered Google 10 times today. This is a simple example of the functionality, but the application is more complex. I have not found documentation regarding:

- If it is possible and how to track a user's visited websites on both iOS and Android

The interaction is as follows: the user installs the application, then the application asks if the user wants to track the websites they visit in their browser. **The browser is the application that the user installs and uses.**

If anyone has experience, knowledge of documentation or frameworks, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577084/android-read-browser-history

Comment: @DanielSpiess thanks